# Function causing java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

Well, all i need to do is this:-
and i got the logic sorted as well(i think i have)
suppose x = 1. 
e are the number of events that occur. if e is 0, then just return 1.
else if, e is 1 or any odd number return x * 2.
else if, e is 2 or any even number return x*2(the value of event e2 -1) + 1.
and so on.
here is my function

```
    public int answer(int f) {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;
    if (f == 0) {
        y = x;
    } else if (f == 1) {
        y = x * 2;
    } else if (f == 2) {
        y = (x * 2) + 1;
    } else if (f % 2 == 0) {
        y = answer(f - 1) + 1;
    } else if (f % 2 != 0) {
        y = answer(f - 1) * 2;

    }

    return y;
}
```

now, the catch is, I can have an arraylist to decide the number of events and have to print out the value of y for all events. the example input would be like:

```
2  //number of events, this is the number of elements that would be in the arraylist.
2  // this event runs for 2 cycles. so the output would be (x * 2) + 1
3  // this event runs for 3 cycles. so the output would be ((x * 2) + 1)*2 (eventcycles-1*2)
```

the error message -

```
Exception in thread "main" 3
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:21)
```

here is my main method to make things clearer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cases = input.nextInt();
    Solution soln = new Solution();
    ArrayList<Integer> casearray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ansarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        int acase = input.nextInt();
        casearray.add(acase);
    }


    for (int elem : casearray) {
        int f = casearray.get(elem); ***//this is the error line***
        int z = soln.answer(f);
        System.out.println(z);
    }

    input.close();

}
```

The question is - why am i getting the indexoutofboundsexception? What is really wrong with my code?
It would be highly appreciated if the answer revolves around my logic, if it is correct that is.

Comment: For there to be an answer there usually has to be a question.

Comment: (And if a question is about an exception then the *complete* exception message should be included in the question, along with the exception stack trace.)

Comment: Read my second comment.

Comment: yeah, did not see it at first, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (int elem : casearray) {
        int f = casearray.get(elem); 
...}
```

the `elem` is the element in the array, it is not the index. but `get(int index)` expects the index. The element value could greater than the max index of your arrayList. That's why you got that error.

You just need to do:

```
 for (int elem : casearray) {             
        int z = soln.answer(elem);
        //print...
...}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int elem : casearray) {
    int f = casearray.get(elem); ***//this is the error line***
    int z = soln.answer(f);
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

Your for loop is iterating through each value in your `casearray`, not through the indexes. So when you do `casearray.get(elem)` you're trying to use the value as the index, and it is out of bounds.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
for (int elem : casearray) {
    int z = soln.answer(elem);
    System.out.println(z);
}
```